# Link basic rust program to rlib in a subfolder

Tags: rust, subdirectory

This is my first attempt at rust, I am from a c++ background and trying to get going. So I started to create my project in a folder called `.../rust/`

**Note:** I used this link to get started with the tools: https://medium.com/@wizofe/cross-compiling-rust-for-arm-e-g-raspberry-pi-using-any-os-11711ebfc52b

- I have created the default rust program using: `cargo new --bin rust_test`. This creates `.../rust/rust_test`.
- I can build using: `cargo build` or `cargo build --target=armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf` (for my BeagleBB)

So far so good. Now I want to create a library that I can share with other projects. But I will create it inside the rust_test folder as `.../rust/rust_test/utils`:

- Created the library with: `cargo new --lib utils`
- I can build my utils in side the `utils` dir with: `cargo build`, this generates a .rlib file.
- Now I wanted to get my rust_test project to build it as a dependency, I found I just had to add: `utils = { path = "utils" }` to my rust_test .toml file.
- Now I can build my rust_test executable and my utils lib in the rust_test folder with `cargo build`

Again, all good so far. The final part of the puzzle for me is to use the function within my utils library. There are two functions in there. One called `adder(a,b)` - an attempt at a template function, and a basic function called `test123()`. This is where I have got stuck. I can't seem to formulate the correct syntax to call either of these functions.

Here are my main files:

### rust_test

location:  `.../rust/rust_test/`

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "rust_test"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["test@gmail.com <test@gmail.com>"]
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
utils = { path = "utils" }
```

**main.rs**

```
mod utils;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");

    utils::test123();    // ??? - does not work
}
```

### utils

location:  `.../rust/rust_test/utils/`

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "utils"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["test@gmail.com <test@gmail.com>"]
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
```

**lib.rs**

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    #[test]
    fn adder<T>(a: T, b: T) -> T {
        return a + b;
    }
}

#[cfg(utils)]
mod utils {
    #[utils]

    fn test123() {
        println!("test!");
    }
}
```

### The output

```
~/bbb/development/rust/rust_test$ cargo build
   Compiling rust_test v0.1.0 (/home/user/bbb/development/rust_test)
error[E0583]: file not found for module `utils`
 --> src/main.rs:1:1
  |
1 | mod utils;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = help: to create the module `utils`, create file "src/utils.rs"

error[E0425]: cannot find function `test123` in module `utils`
 --> src/main.rs:6:12
  |
6 |     utils::test123();    // ??? - does not work
  |            ^^^^^^^ not found in `utils`

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0425, E0583.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0425`.
error: could not compile `rust_test`.
```

I have to admit I don't really understand what the `#[cfg...]` and `#[...]` lines do. But from what I have read I thought the `mod utils;` in main.rs tells the rust compiler/linker to look else where for the test123() function.

Maybe I have not even linked the files at all yet - I have only built them?

So the question is what do I need to do now to link my library to my application so I can use the lib function `test123()`?

**update**

if I remove `mod utils;` I get the error:

```
user@user-VirtualBox:~/bbb/development/rust/rust_test$ cargo build
   Compiling rust_test v0.1.0 (/home/user/bbb/development/rust_test)
error[E0425]: cannot find function `test123` in crate `utils`
 --> src/main.rs:4:12
  |
4 |     utils::test123();    // ??? - does not work
  |            ^^^^^^^ not found in `utils`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0425`.
error: could not compile `rust_test`.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that getting rid of `mod utils;` in `main.rs` should
solve your problem.

`mod utils;` in `main.rs` tells the compiler that
`utils` is an inner module of your application (but it
does not exist so does not contain the functions you are
looking for), although it is actually a crate (external
to your application).

The module system helps organise the details inside a crate
while a crate is seen as a library.

---

**edit**

You should also get rid of `#[cfg(utils)]` in `lib.rs` because
it means that the following item exists only if the `utils`
feature is set in your `Cargo.toml` file (which is not
the case).
The `cfg()` directives are intended for conditional compilation.
( https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html )

And sorry, I forgot, `mod utils {}` in `lib.rs` may not be necessary,
or you will need to refer to the function as `utils::utils::test123()`
from your application.
The first `utils` refers to the crate, the second `utils` refers to
an inner module of this crate.

Comment: I added the `mod utils;` because I was already getting an error. I updated the question at the very end to show the error I get if I remove `mod utils;`. So I think I am still missing something

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have removed the two `#[]` lines in/around my mod utils within lib.rs (and removed the `mod utils;`) now I get the error: `cannot find function 'test123' in crate 'utils'`. This is a step closer - at least it is now trying to look in the crate utils... but it does not find the function...

Comment: ah ha! - that got it, well it got me to the next error, which was `function test123 is private`, but after a quick google I just put `pub` infront of it and then my compile worked. Thanks very much :)